# Padding behaving like Margin

Tags: css, html, margin, padding

I have two divs side by side within a wrapper div.  They fit perfectly and display correctly.  However, when I try to add padding to the left side of the left hand div, it not only moves the contents of that div over to the right, but it actually moves the content of the right hand div over as well!  If I add anything over 20px of padding it actually moves the right hand div to down to the next row!  How on earth is this possible?  Posting CSS and HTML below.  The wrapper div is "hwrapper".  The left hand div is "rbox", and the right hand div is "card".  As I said, adding padding to the left side of "rbox" moves the content of "card" to the right as well.  How can I fix this?

```
    #header {
    height:800px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    background:url(/assets/header-tail.gif) 0 0 repeat-x #f7f7f7;
    }
#hwrapper {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    }
#header .logo {
    padding: 3px;
    text-align: center; 
    }
#rbox {
    background:url(/assets/hredbox.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    height: 420px;
    width: 274px;   
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 10px; 
    }
#card {
    margin-left: auto;
    height: 420px;
    width: 720px;
    background:url(/assets/silverbackh360b0.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    float: right; 
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 20px;
    }
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="header">
    <div class="logo"><%= link_to image_tag("etlogo.png",alt:"Logo"), 'index.html' %></div>
    <div id="hwrapper">
        <div id="rbox"><span><center>Some Text</center></span><br><p><br>
            <dl>
            A list goes here.
            </dl><br><p><br>
                <span><center>Log In Here</center></span>
        </div>
        <div id="card">Lots more text in here.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I was under the belief that padding only effected elements within a block, and margin effected the relationship between blocks.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Testing in both Chrome and Firefox.  Same results in both.

Comment: You know that when you add padding to a div it increases the div's entire width? My assumption is that by adding padding you're actually making the width of the two inside divs greater than that of the outside div, which is causing them to shift down.

Comment: Wait, what?  By adding padding I increase the width of the division?  Are you sure?  That makes absolutely no sense.  How would one position things within a division without mucking up surrounding divisions?

Comment: Padding and margins both affect the layout of other elements. I would do some reading on the box model - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model - Also, there is no reason to use `<center>`. It is depreciated and bad practice.

Comment: I was just reading up on this, thanks.  That is the most counter-intuitive thing I have ever heard.  What an awful spec.  I guess the solution is to put another div within that div with a narrower width and add a left margin.  What nonsense.  Thanks for the response, though.

Comment: If it was all easy and intuitive, Blind Fish, we wouldn't have 5 million questions here on SO!

Comment: Spaceman817, if you find this comment please summarize your comments as an answer so I can accept it.  I hate leaving an open question and your comments did answer my question, so you should get the credit.  Thanks.

Comment: @Blind Fish  : Yes it is very counter-intuitive .  I assume that is the reason they later came up with "box-Sizing : border-box" which fixes exactly the issue of actual width being affected by padding-left when "width:" is specified in the CSS. The old way  with "box-sizing: content-box" is very counter-intuitive  because the width you get to show on the page  is not the width you specify in your CSS with  "width:"

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue as well. Make sure you use box-sizing. Try applying this code:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This allows you to use padding within a div and not expand it's width.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I had the following HTML:

```
<div style =
" padding-left  : 12px;
  position      : absolute;
  left          : 0px;
  width         : 120px;
  border        : solid 1px RED;
```

To my surprise when I changed padding-left from 0px to 12px, the red right-border moved 12px to the right. Very annoying.

I was able to stop this happening by adding  'box-sizing: border-box' to the style. The annoying moving right-border is gone with this addition:

```
<div style =
" padding-left  : 12px;
  box-sizing    :  border-box;

  position      : absolute;
  left          : 0px;
  width         : 120px;
  border        : solid 1px RED ;
```

So "box-sizing:border-box" solved this problem.
The reason I found the original behavior so counter-intuitive at first was that I was using ABSOLUTE positioning, so I assumed that "width:120px" would have absolutely positioned the right-border at 120px. And I assume it would do something like that if I said: "right:120px;", but that would mean 120px from the right edge of the page.

In summary padding-left: affects the position of the right border if

1. You use 'width:' (rather than 'right:')  and
2. You don't specify "box-sizing:border-box"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the width of the 2 divs, including the padding (i.e. if its 25px wide with 5px of padding all around its actually 35px wide) doesn't exceed the width of the container div.

Answer (score 0):

Just subtract padding (left and right) from width of div with this padding and everything should be ok.